# error while updating composer in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I got this error while updating composer.

```
 - Removing symfony/debug (v2.6.4)
  - Installing symfony/debug (v2.6.12)
    Downloading: Connecting...
Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/debug/zipball/fca5696e0c9787722baa8f2ad6940dfd7a6a6941, please create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+DESKTOP-8ON1O73+2015-12-10+1252
to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "C:/Users/test/AppData/Roaming/Composer/auth.json" for future use by Composer.
Token (hidden):
```

I followed thw laravel 5 installing from the offical website itself.

Comment: follow the orders .. go here https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+DESKTOP-8ON1O73+2015-12-10+1252, obey :)

Answer (score 3):

It just says that GitHub is limiting the amount of packages you can fetch without authorization. Simply follow the link as it says in the text, thus allowing composer to fetch the packages through your credentials instead. You should probably read the error text, before posting it to stack overflow.